# How can I dynamically add new content to my page each time my array length increases?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is adding new strings to an array at random intervals. How can I display with javascript and/or jquery each new string on my page every time the length of the array increases?

Comment: Looking into AngularJS (best solution) or use jQuery to set HTML on an element like: `$("span.array_length").html( array_name.length );` and `<span class="array_length">0</span>`

Comment: You can use an interactive library like Angular, React, Vue, ... . Or, use a native JavaScript interval and check the array each time

Comment: It would help to have some code.  Can the function that is adding the strings just use jQuery's `.append()`?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100376/how-to-watch-for-array-changes) should help get your answer.

Comment: You can also use a library like @Mojtaba said. I personally like [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a recursive timer function that will updated your array display container every time it is called (adapted from [Javascript dynamic array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357614/javascript-dynamic-array-of-strings)):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var arr = [];
            function add() {
              arr.push("String " + Math.random());
            }
            function show() {
              var html = '';
              for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                html += '<div>' + arr[i] + '</div>';
              }
              var con = document.getElementById('container');
              con.innerHTML = html;
            }
            function start() {
              setTimeout(function() {
                add();
                // Note: you can call show in an independent timeout
                show();
                start();
              }, 1000);
            }
        </script>

        <input type="button" onclick="start();" value="start" />
        <br />
        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you can make it smarter and update the container only if the array's length changed.

Yet another way is to pass a display container update callback to your array update function, so that whenever you update your array - you just go and re-display your array.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var arr = [];
            var lastDisplayed = 0;

            function add() {
              arr.push("String #" + lastDisplayed + ": " + Math.random());
              show(); // Update display container
            };
            function show() {
              var node;
              var textnode;
              var container = document.getElementById('container'); // Get parent container
              for (; lastDisplayed < arr.length; lastDisplayed++) {
                node = document.createElement("li"); // Create a <li> node
                textnode = document.createTextNode(arr[lastDisplayed]); // Create a text node
                node.appendChild(textnode);        
                container.appendChild(node);
              }
            };
            function start() {
              setTimeout(function() {
                add();
                start();
              }, 1000);
            };
        </script>

        <input type="button" onclick="start();" value="start" />
        <br />
        <ul id="container"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Internally, Angular and other frameworks implement a combination of these approaches.

Important note: depending on your application, you might want to explore different approaches to updating your page to preserve responsiveness and performance of your interface. For example, you might want to space your GUI updates in time if array elements are added too often. You may also want to keep adding elements to your DOM model (see the second example) instead of rewriting it (like in the first example) if the existing elements of your array remain unchanged. Similar issues might need to be considered if using a dedicated framework like Angular.

Comment: There are all types of problems with this.  Using innerHTML like this would cause all done elements to be rewritten to the screen every time.  At a minimum it would cause the UI to spaz and at worse it would cause serious performance issues.  Native javascript has append and prepend methods for adding DOM elements on the fly, and since he referenced jQuery this is not a great suggestion IMHO

Comment: Updated last example with JavaScript append. My answer focused on the ways to update GUI based on the updates to the data - it is hard to know what the question author is after without a more detailed context. Performance considerations might deserve their own thread.

Comment: Doesn't look like the op cares anyways.  Love when I take time to help and they just leave my response hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library that handle property subscriptions like knockout or angular, but since that wasnt mentioned in the question I will give this example.

```
var someArray = [];
var standardPush = someArray.push;
someArray.push = function(){
    // depending on your requirements you can switch these next two lines around
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
       updateUI(arguments[i]); // call code to update UI
       standardPush(arguments[i]); // actually ad record to array   
    }
}
function updateUI(record){
  // Some code that updates your UI
  // example
  $("#container").append($("<div>").text(record));
}
```

then just call it like a normal array.push

```
someArray.push(someRecord);    
// or
someArray(record1, record2, record3....);
```

This code is more fun than practical, I again would recommend a library that handles property subscriptions.